# How can I form dynamic navigation in my site

Tags: php, dynamic, foreach, navigation

I have a numerous amount of routes a user could take in my site, for example if they are one particular user, they get different navigation compared to another user.

Dependant on what sector a user is, I have created a switch statement to capture these id's and construct their unique navigation titles:

```
switch($sector_id){
    /*chefs
    case 'f8721714d845eaa5222dcdb4dd642ceb29a280bc':
        $key_array= array('menus','news','staff','directory');
        $url_array = array('/dashboard/menus/','/dashboard/news2/','/dashboard/staff2/','/dashboard/directory2/');
        $name_array = array('Menus2','News2','Staff2','Directory2');'Recipe Stories', 'Blog', 'Events');
        break;*/
    //restaurants, pubs
    case 'c835ff2d2838b3ea45bdb729c641b73b4fa0098d':
    case '378ee5253530d7d02cea3012966deab24bcc5da2':
        $key_array= array('menus','news','staff','directory');
        $url_array = array('/dashboard/menus/','/dashboard/news/','/dashboard/staff/','/dashboard/directory/');
        $name_array = array('Menus','News','Staff','Directory');
        break;
```

So for example this is what I already have (hard coded):

```
array(  'key'   =>  'profile',
        'url'   =>  '/dashboard/profile/',
        'name'  =>  'Profile'),
array(  'key'   =>  'picture',
        'url'   =>  '/dashboard/picture/',
        'name'  =>  'Profile Picture'),
array(  'key'   =>  'cv',
        'url'   =>  '/dashboard/cv/',
        'name'  =>  'CV').
```

How can I dynamically construct the arrays above? I could use a for each statement, but their would have to be nested right? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought about creating static navigation html for each user type and just including the file base on user type?  This would may be easier for you if you don't want to go "All Out" on dynamic navigation.  Your hard coding your navigation anyway...

or

If you want to be truly dynamic, store all of your navigation items in a table (id, key, url, name) and create a join table for user type and navigation items.

Join Table Columns:
(usertype, navigation_id)

Join Table SQL (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM usertype_navigation un JOIN navigation_items ni on un.navigation_id = ni.id WHERE un.usertype = "c835ff2d2838b3ea45bdb729c641b73b4fa0098d"
```

This will return all the navigation items, loop through each record and spit out the html for the navigation item.